# How can i add a cron job run every minute to my elearning site on moodle?

Tags: moodle, recycle-bin

I try to add a cron job on an elearning.mysite.gr(Moodle). Although my host gives this message every hour.
Oct  2 1:10:01 linux CROND[123456]: (admin) CMD (touch /tmp/test.txt  > /dev/null)

On my site administration -> notifications get this message:
The admin/cli/cron.php script has not been run for 3 days 2 hours and should run every 1 min.

At moodle documentation
/path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php, can i use it ? in which way ?

I tried this :
/usr/bin/php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php

but gives me that the process completed with error at one minute
only this touch /tmp/test.txt  > /dev/null
completed with success.

Moodle Documentation:
The CLI (command line interpreter) script. This will be at the path ***/path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php***
If in doubt, this is the correct script to use. This needs to be run by a 'PHP CLI' program on your computer. So the final command may look something like /usr/bin/php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php You can (and should) try this on your command line to see if it works. **WARNING: Check your command-line PHP version is compatible with your chosen version of Moodle**.-How to check it?
The command-line PHP program is different to the one running your web site and is not always the same version.

I don't know what to do...I will appreciate any help!!!

I tried by my host panel interface :

**Type of progress:**

1. Command line
2. URL
3. PHP
   i should choose one from 3.

**Command***:
placeholder to add my command to be excecuted

**Excecute**:
Dropdown
1.Cron style
2.Daily at  00:00

**I use command line.**
touch /tmp/test.txt
When i add
**cron style** and 1 * * * * * , get message for syntax.
and for
**daily** at 00:00 success message  but on my notification of my site has
The admin/cli/cron.php script has not been run for 17 days 22 hours and should run every 1 min.

[image]

That's the icon of my Plesk Login. To change the path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php xould i check the file manager in order to find cron.php file ??

[image]

Comment: You can access your server with ssh and run Linux command?
Or have you set up the cron from a web interface on your host?

Comment: on my host interface try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

As you add the cron from a web interface (maybe Plesk ?) you only need this part:

```
 /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php
```

replace  /path/to/moodle/ with the real path on your server, usulay something like /var/www/moodle/ or /var/www/vhosts/domain.name/httpdocs/moodle

To run every 1 minute cron style is :

```
* * * * *
```

If you can choose PHP version, choose the same version as the one you are using for Moodle.

Comment: Yes I tried these. But get that the process completed with error. 
Could i have some more information,please? 

1) /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php  -> I should choose the First option?Excute  Command?

2)replace /path/to/moodle/ with the real path on your server, you mean my domain name? I don't know path of my server I only manage a site with the role of admin.
So, i have the last choice  /var/www/vhosts/domain.name/httpdocs/moodle with the PHP choice.

Comment: and I add the * * * * * 
 in front of the / path / ,,, / ... / ?? or choose the cron tab ->because when i add them there(cron tab) i get error syntax...

Comment: Are you on Plesk? If so, you can try /var/www/vhosts/domain.name/httpdocs/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php

Comment: * * * * * should be written in cron style field

Comment: thank you .... i tried again... and may find out the solution !! I have tried for months...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I give this touch /tmp/test.txt ->and at cron style the touch /tmp/test.txt, as you suggest to me.

Because the other commands cannot complete with success.
But in my notifications,(Site administration-Moodle) i still get the message that cron don't run.